# Running method using Spring @Scheduled annotation

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have a a single method annotated with the @Scheduled annotation in Spring, scheduled to run every 2 seconds.

```
@Schedule(fixedDelay=2000)
public void myOperation() {

    ...
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    ...
    ...
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

However, the underling operations being done have sleep() introduced in order to have delays (for a specific use case). Now if the delays add up to more than 2 seconds, I am trying to understand if Spring will spin up a new thread for the next scheduled operation? Or would it wait till the current thread finishes executing and then start the new one?

Also, to prevent the number of threads from exploding to a large amount, is it safe to provide a thread pool size so that there's no sudden increase in the number of threads running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `fixedDelay` you are specifying the time to wait since the process has finished until start it again. If your process sleeps in between it does not matter. It needs to finish to the `fixedDelay` time starts counting. So, you are going to have only one thread active in this case.

On the other hand, if want to start a process every two seconds, without considering whether the previous task has finish or not, you need to use `fixedRate`. In this case, if you want to be sure there are not more than X process running at the same time, you should use a `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`.

Have a look to the documentation:

[Annotation Type Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#fixedDelay--)

[ThreadPoolTaskScheduler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-task-namespace)

Answer (score -1):

If You want to have scheduled tasks and control threads by yourself, than it's better to use [ScheduledPoolExecutor](http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/multi-threading/task-scheduling-with-executors-scheduledthreadpoolexecutor-example/)

Comment: Your answer should be a comment